# HTML Button not responding to the CSS in live using dreamweaver

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

Hello everyone I'm having an issue with my HMTL and the CSS assigned to it not working. The button works, it will link over as it should but the CSS is not effecting it. 
I use dreamweaver CC and in design view it seems like the CSS is working but once i live view it on browser it reverts back to its original state I'll provide a few pictures of the code and live view to show you what I mean.

My HTML

```
<a href="methandrailhome.html" class="returnhome">Return Home</a><!-- end .returnhome -->
```

MY CSS

```
#form .returnhome {

    -moz-box-shadow:inset -4px 2px 0px -13px #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset -4px 2px 0px -13px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:inset -4px 2px 0px -13px #ffffff;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #f9f9f9), color-stop(1, #e9e9e9) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f9f9f9', endColorstr='#e9e9e9');
    background-color:#f9f9f9;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
    border-top-left-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
    border-top-right-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    text-indent:-1.9px;
    border:2px solid #dcdcdc;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#666666;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    width:95px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 0px #ffffff;
}
```

```css
    .returnhome {
     
     -moz-box-shadow:inset -4px 2px 0px -13px #ffffff;
     -webkit-box-shadow:inset -4px 2px 0px -13px #ffffff;
     box-shadow:inset -4px 2px 0px -13px #ffffff;
     background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #f9f9f9), color-stop(1, #e9e9e9) );
     background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100% );
     filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f9f9f9', endColorstr='#e9e9e9');
     background-color:#f9f9f9;
     -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
     -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
     border-top-left-radius:0px;
     -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
     -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
     border-top-right-radius:0px;
     -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
     -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
     border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
     -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
     -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
     border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
     text-indent:-1.9px;
     border:2px solid #dcdcdc;
     display:inline-block;
     color:#666666;
     font-family:Arial;
     font-size:13px;
     font-weight:bold;
     font-style:normal;
     height:40px;
     line-height:40px;
     width:95px;
     text-decoration:none;
     text-align:center;
     text-shadow:0px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    }
```

```html
<a href="#" class="returnhome">Return Home</a>
```

[Here is what live view from Dreamwweaver is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZaii.png)

Comment: For some reason the HTML didn't show here is the HTML button 

<a href="methandrailhome.html" class="returnhome">Return Home</a><!-- end .returnhome -->

Comment: Is the anchor within your form, and does your form have id='form'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take that `#form` out.

```css
.returnhome {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset -4px 2px 0px -13px #ffffff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset -4px 2px 0px -13px #ffffff;
  box-shadow: inset -4px 2px 0px -13px #ffffff;
  background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #f9f9f9), color-stop(1, #e9e9e9));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient( center top, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f9f9f9', endColorstr='#e9e9e9');
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  text-indent: -1.9px;
  border: 2px solid #dcdcdc;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #666666;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 95px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<a href="methandrailhome.html" class="returnhome">Return Home</a>
```